# Meaning of 一文にもならない from Super Mario RPG. (With pictures)

Tags: meaning

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSZ60.jpg

This is from a video teaching Japanese meaning from Super Mario RPG.
Source: https://youtu.be/1LMxshr0BE4?t=497

The context is: Mario and Mallow(little white puff ball) are trying to get a coin back from Croco(purple guy). Croco has been punched by Mallow, then basically says Mario and Mallow can have the coin back.

The part I am confused about is 一文にもならない. The creator of the video says it means 'worthless'.

How does the video creator know this? I cannot find any meaning of this online so I just want to be sure this is correct. Thank you.

Comment: 文 is an old term for money, so 一文 is a dollar, or a cent or whatever. 一文にならない is “not worth a dollar”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a set phrase meaning *worthless*, as you can see an equivalent 一文の値打ちもない in [this dictionary entry.](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E4%B8%80%E6%96%87/#je-3614)

文{もん} is an old unit of money, and 一文 is the tiny amount of money ([jisho](https://jisho.org/word/%E4%B8%80%E6%96%87-1)) and なる here means *to amount to* ([jisho](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B) #7), so the whole phrase literally means *does not amount to a cent*.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you!